# Getting rid of overfull \hbox message in exam class for wider footers

Tags: exam, footer

In an effort to increase the footer width in the `exam` class, I adapted the solution provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253935/14103). This works nicely. However, it is generating overfull `\hbox` warning messages. This is a bit personal, but I always try to get rid of all the warning messages.

Please see the MWE.

```
\documentclass{exam}

% Page dimensions
\usepackage[dvips,pdftex,legalpaper,top=10.0mm,bottom=20.0mm,includeheadfoot,left=20.0mm,right=35.0mm]{geometry}

% Footer
\newlength\footerwidth
\setlength\footerwidth{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\footerwidth}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\footerwidth}{\marginparsep}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@fullfoot}{\hbox to \textwidth}{\hbox to \footerwidth}%
{}{\errmessage{Patching of \noexpand\run@fullfoot failed}}
\patchcmd{\run@fullfoot}{\hbox to \textwidth}{\hbox to \footerwidth}%
{}{\errmessage{Patching of \noexpand\run@fullfoot failed}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{foot}
\footer{}{}{Page \thepage}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question [10] How do I get rid of the annoying overfull message?
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

I want to get rid of the warning messages like,

> ```
> Overfull \hbox (41.135pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
> []
> ```

I know that I need to put `\begingroup\hfuzz\maxdimen\endgroup` around some code but can not find the exact place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a different approach... Instead of increasing the *entire* footer width, you can just insert a negative space after/before the right/left footer to push it into the margin.

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}

% Page dimensions
\usepackage[
  top=10mm,
  bottom=20mm,
  includeheadfoot,
  left=20mm,
  right=35mm
]{geometry}

% Footer
\pagestyle{foot}
\footer{}% <left>
  {}% <center>
  {Page \thepage\hspace*{-\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}}% <right>

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question [10] How do I get rid of the annoying overfull message?
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This uses the same idea as Werner's answer, but you can do it simply without using the geometry package:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\pagestyle{foot}
\footer{}% Empty Left
  {}% Empty Center
  {\rlap{\enskip Page \thepage}}
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question [10] How do I get rid of the annoying overfull message?
\end{questions}

Here's some text to show the margins.
Here's some text to show the margins.
Here's some text to show the margins.
Here's some text to show the margins.
Here's some text to show the margins.
Here's some text to show the margins.
Here's some text to show the margins.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This will not have the right footer right-aligned.

Comment: That's true.  If you want it right-aligned, you can put a fixed width box inside the argument of \rlap with the contenst of that box right justified.

Answer (score 1):

This version uses `\makebox` to cram a `\footerwidth` `\hbox` into a `\textwidth` space.

```
\documentclass{exam}

% Page dimensions
\usepackage[dvips,pdftex,legalpaper,top=10.0mm,bottom=20.0mm,includeheadfoot,left=20.0mm,right=35.0mm,showframe]{geometry}

% Footer
\newlength\footerwidth
\setlength\footerwidth{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\footerwidth}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\footerwidth}{\marginparsep}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myfoot}[1]{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\hbox to \footerwidth{#1}}}
\patchcmd{\@fullfoot}{\hbox to \textwidth}{\myfoot}%
{}{\errmessage{Patching of \noexpand\run@fullfoot failed}}
\patchcmd{\run@fullfoot}{\hbox to \textwidth}{\myfoot}%
{}{\errmessage{Patching of \noexpand\run@fullfoot failed}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{foot}
\footer{}{}{Page \thepage}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question [10] How do I get rid of the annoying overfull message?
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```